# how to choose another API in Android SDK Manager revision 22.0.5

Tags: android

I would like to buy a smartphone with android 4.1.2 gelly bean

but I don't know if my apks will run on it.
At the moment I use 4.2.2. API in my Android SDK Manager Revision 22.0.5
Will it run on this smartphone?

If not, how can I change my API in the SDK?
Simply instal a previous API and create an emulator and then choose another target for the project?

Comment: what is the `android:minSdkVersion` you have set in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="17"

Comment: ok but how do I know this will work? is there a list of comparison between sdkversion numer and android version number?

Comment: I found this: [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html)

Comment: You just need to provide minSdkVersion number. This will allow you to give backward compatibility my friend.